# Excel 2010 if condition occurs in column

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-2010

i was not really sure how to call the title, but i think this just about describes it.

I want to make a table in Excel 2010 and it looks something like the following:

Table1:

No.  | Name | Hours available | Leftover hours |
1    | John | 40 |   | 
2    | Pete | 35 |   | 
3    | Jane | 24 |   |

Table2:

No.  | Client | Hours needed | Who? | 
1    | Client 1 | 4 | John | 
2    | Client 2 | 16 | Jane | 
3    | Client 3 | 8 | Pete | 
4    | Client 4 | 9 | John |

In the column 'leftover hours' in table 1, i want the formula to take place. The formula has to check according to the name of it's row, in table 2 if it occurs there, and if it occurs, take the 'Hours needed'. Then take the 'Hours available' and subtract the 'Hours needed' and output the result in its 'Leftover hours'.

In this example; John should have 27 leftover hours, Pete should have 27 leftover hours and Jane should have 8 leftover hours.

I hope what i try to accomplish is clear and i would really appreciate if someone is willing to help me.

Comment: In the future you should include examples of what formulas you have tried so far, and what has failed with those formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Extra column (E) in table 2, fill down: `=SUMIF($D$2:$D$5,D2,$C$2:$C$5)`

Last column in table 1, fill down: `=C2-INDEX('table 2'!E:E,MATCH('table 1'!B2,'table 2'!D:D,0),0,1)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the `SUMIFS` function:

http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/sumifs.php

So your leftover hours column would look something like:

`=SUMIFS([Table2]$C$2:$C$5,[Table2]$D$2:$D$5,"=B2")`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is fairly straightforward, and requires 3 functions. First, it requires the formulas INDEX & MATCH in combination (this is similar to VLOOKUP, if you are familiar with that, but it allows you to have your 'index column' to the right of your 'result column'). Start with the MATCH formula - it finds the row in table 2 which matches the name from table 1 [assumes the names in table 1 are in column A, and the names in table 2 are in column C on sheet2; this formula is for the 2nd row in table 1]:

```
=Match(A2,sheet2!C:C,0)
```

Then use this in the INDEX function, which provides you with the data from a given column, at a specified row number:

```
=Index(sheet2!B:B,Match(A2,sheet2!C:C,0))
```

Then, subtract from the current available hours, and wrap that in an IFERROR function - which checks to see if a value was found using the above INDEX & MATCH. If a value was found, it keeps it; if an error was found, we tell it to give "".

```
=Iferror(B2-Index(sheet2!B:B,Match(A2,sheet2!C:C,0)),"")
```

And that's it - just drag down for the rest of your table1 data.

**EDIT** Note that it was pointed out to me that there are multiple results for the same name from table 2; therefore SUMIFS is required as suggested by other answers.

Comment: You're missing the 2nd argument for IFERROR. Also, this does not sum the values in table two.

Comment: @tonester640 Agreed; this won't work with duplicate values.

Comment: @pnuts I see what you're saying; in my mind I find there's less need for stringency with Excel Formulas than with Excel VBA. Mostly because when someone wants a VBA solution (and haven't attempted one) they often don't understand anything but how to press the button. As a matter of principle I think running VBA when you can't read it to be dangerous [for fear of malicious code] and disruptive to one's own career progression [not learning to fix problems]. However with formulas, people often at least understand formula concepts which can be explained step-by-step.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder whether most of the Excel Formula questions should even be here vs Superuser, but I think the complexity of some questions bleeds into SO more adequately, and this creates a grey area where, in my opinion, 'softer' Excel Formula questions exist here and benefit  from doing so. This is personal preference I suppose, and perhaps my answering similar Formula quesitons is part of the same problem of 'allowing bad questions to be answered'. Still, I try not to do so where the problem is not well laid out with data examples.